# ionic.bundle.js:25642 Error: [ngRepeat:iexp] Expected expression in form of '_item_ in _collection_[ track by _id_]' but got 'cdata.catagoriesdata'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to create a ionic mobile app in that i am getting an error in ng-repeat the error is

> ionic.bundle.js:25642 Error: [ngRepeat:iexp] Expected expression in form of '*item* in *collection*[ track by *id*]' but got 'cdata.catagoriesdata'

please any one help me to solve this issue then i have added my code below

```js
.controller('categoriesdatactrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams) {
   $scope.catagoriesdata=[{"title":"anandan"},{"title":"anandan1"}];

}])
```

```html
<ion-view title="Categories" id="page3">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
        
        <ion-list id="categories-list2" ng-repeat="cdata.catagoriesdata">
            <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left assertive" id="categories-list-item20" >
                 
                <h2>{{cdata.title}}</h2>
            </ion-item>
                    
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your ng-repeat like this

```
ng-repeat="cdata in catagoriesdata track by $index"
```

Comment: without track by $index  it working fine thanks for your answer